# MarkLogic incorrectly orders results by score

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm encountering a very strange issue with MarkLogic's `search:search()` function. When using a constraint option, it seems like it does not sort by score correctly. Below is an edited version of the function I am calling to search:

```
declare function s:book-search(
        $query as xs:string*,
        $subjects as xs:string*,
        $start as xs:unsignedLong?,
        $page-length as xs:unsignedLong?)  as element(search:response){
        
    let $subject-ids :=  fn:tokenize($subjects, ',')
    let $subject-query := 
        if(fn:count($subject-ids) > 0)
        then
            for $id in $subject-ids            
                return 'metadata/subject/'||$id       
        else
            ()
    
    let $options := 
        <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
            <searchable-expression xmlns:m="http://replacedrealwebsite.com/collection/book-metadata">
                /m:metadata
            </searchable-expression>
            <constraint name="subject">
                <collection prefix="metadata/subject/" facet="true" />
            </constraint>
            {
               if(fn:count($subject-query) > 0)
               then
                   <additional-query>{cts:collection-query($subject-query)}</additional-query>
               else
                   ()
            }
            <term>
                <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
                <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
                <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
            </term>
            <sort-order direction="descending">
                <score/>
            </sort-order>
            <transform-results apply="empty-snippet"/>
            <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
        </options>

    return search:search($query, $options, $start, $page-length)    
};
```

If I pass any `$subjects` in, without a `$query` parameter, the results are ordered incorrectly, but also ordered in a strange manner. For example, here is a list of the scores in the order they were returned from a test call with a large page length to see all the results:

```
[
  "7808768",
  "334592",
  "285952",
  "197120",
  "113408",
  "74496",
  "34816",
  "7808256",
  "7705856",
  "7694592",
  "2031360",
  "1144832",
  "629504",
  "181760",
  "145664",
  "70656",
  "62208",
  "57856",
  "-208384",
  "8101632",
  "7853056",
...
]
```

As you can see, the highest score is not the first result. Additionally, it sorts in descending order, but then it will "jump" up to a high score, and then descend again. I can't seem to identify any pattern or order.

What makes this stranger is that if I add a non-blank `$query` parameter, the scores are ordered correctly! Here is an example of the scores when I pass in a simple word to the `$query` parameter:

```
[
  "8403200",
  "8154624",
  "8153856",
  "8110336",
  "8109824",
  "8007424",
  "7988992",
  "7982080",
  "5464320",
  "2332928",
  "1456128",
  "931072",
  "587520",
  "509440",
  "483328",
  "447232",
  "435200",
  "429312",
  "424704",
  "381952",
  "376064",
  "373504",
...
]
```

I've been trying to fiddle with the search options for a while and am at a loss as to why this is happening. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The MarkLogic version I'm running on is 10.0-6.4

I should also note that this issue is not happening on a test server running 10.0 with identical code, which makes me think this is a bug with MarkLogic or a small difference between versions that I'm missing.

Edit: Another odd thing that I've noticed is that if I change the sort to

```
<sort-order direction="ascending">
   <score/>
</sort-order>
```

then the results are returned in the correct ascending order. So it is only descending order that is broken.